# How to get the labels of nodes and egdes from read_dot

Tags: python, graph, networkx, dot

I have a dot file representing a Directed Graph (`DiGraph`). I want that to be read in a networkx DiGraph object. 
I used the `networkx.drawing.nx_agraph.read_dot(PATH)`, however **the nodes in the graph this function returns are just simple `'str'` types and the labels are all lost in translation**.

Dotfile is like this:

```
digraph code {
    graph [bgcolor=white fontname="Courier" splines="ortho"];
    node [fillcolor=gray style=filled shape=box];
    edge [arrowhead="normal"];
    "0x000052c0" -> "0x00003a40" [label="section..text" color="red" URL="section..text/0x00003a40"];
    "0x00003a40" [label="section..text" URL="section..text/0x00003a40"];
    "0x000052c0" -> "0x0021ee08" [label="reloc.__libc_start_main_8" color="green" URL="reloc.__libc_start_main_8/0x0021ee08"];
    "0x0021ee08" [label="reloc.__libc_start_main_8" URL="reloc.__libc_start_main_8/0x0021ee08"];
}
```

What I wrote to read this file is this:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.drawing.nx_agraph.read_dot(DOT_GRAPH_NAME)
```

Does anyone have a better method? I could write my own but it's better to have something working and tested.

Comment: A better method for what?  Rendering the graph?  And if you'll show us your DOT file maybe we can help.

Comment: I mean a better method to read the dot file into a netwoorkx graph object. The dot file is huge but I will post a couple of lines

Comment: Focus on a usable portion of the diagram that can be rendered, a small subset, and let's see if we can solve your label problem.

Comment: I added a simple sample that can be rendered. The nodes that are read are only the addresses in quotes. The things in brackets are all lost. edges are something with the arrow notation between 2 nodes

Comment: Clearly the networkx thing isn't respecting the correct dot syntax, because your graph looks just fine to me using GraphViz 2.38.  If you want I'll post an answer based on that.

Comment: @TomServo Hi! Thank you for bringing this up but I found the problem. The attributes of a node/edge were not stored in the node/edge but I had to do something like nx.get_edge_attributes(G,e) or nx.get_node_attributes(G,n)

Answer (score 1):

From the source code file [networkx/drawing/nx_agraph.py](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/drawing/nx_agraph.py), the follow code can be found:

```
# add nodes, attributes to N.node_attr
for n in A.nodes():
    str_attr = {str(k): v for k, v in n.attr.items()}
    N.add_node(str(n), **str_attr)
...
N.graph['node'] = dict(A.node_attr)
```

So, the node attributes are also parsed. You can find this field by

```
vars(g)
```

In my case, I can get the label by

```
for node_id in g.nodes:
    print g._node[node_id]['label'] # here, 'node_id' is the 'str' you said
```